# Does the download speed depends on browsers too?

Tags: browser, download

As far my knowledge goes download speed depends on net connection.

I heard that some browsers are fast for downloading files.

Is it true? If so, which is fastest for downloading?

Comment: The differences between the browsers would not effect the speed of which the data is downloaded at at least not enough that you can measure.  The type of differences are in the ms to second ranges.

Comment: In practice, the two most meaningful limitations are download speed are ISP throughput rate, and server output rate. any modern computer can handle far more data inbound per second than the fastest ISPs provide (Gb Fiber might be an exception), so unless the browser was built with very poor code, local resource allocation does not have a big impact on download speed.

Answer (score 3):

It depends to an extent to how your browser is set up, how it renders, and various other factors.

It comes down to *what are you really trying to do*. If we're optimising for actual speed on a fast connection for web browsing, and not caring about the load on the server, we could tweak some settings - turning on [http pipelining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_pipelining) and more aggressive caching - [fasterfox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fasterfox) is an example of a firefox extension that does these things.

On the other hand, with slower network connections, you may want to compress the content - using [http compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression), or if you want to be more agressive, reformat, and pre-process the content for smaller sizes like [opera turbo](http://www.opera.com/turbo) does.

As you might notice, different strategies work better for different situations - in most scenarios though, the difference would be small - I used the opera turbo trick to deal with a particularly slow connection when on holiday.

For actual downloads of files, one stratergy that works well for me on fast connections would be to use a software that allows parallel downloads - I used to use FDM, or axel, and it was significantly faster than say, wget, or downloading using my browser.

As with anything, you're not going to find the most optimal solution without testing.

Comment: Actually I was trying to download VS2012 trial version that is 1GB+.  My net speed is a bit slow so it was showing 1hr+ time for downloading the file(this was on firefox). Someone told chrome would download file faster, that's the reason I had this question.

Answer (score 0):

> I heard that some browsers are fast for downloading files.

Not really, while some browsers can render the pages faster and do cute little tricks like prefectch, and paralell downloads, if you're really maxing your download, you're maxing your download.